# How to maximize a MATLAB figure to full screen?

Tags: matlab, figure

I am creating some figures in MATLAB and I have a command that I run that coverts them to .eps after the figure is created.

However, I want the figures to be maximized before they are saved to .eps. I am looking for a command that tells MATLAB to resize the figure to the screen size. Then I want to run my function which saves to a .eps.

Is there such a way?

I have heard it may be possible to specify the pixel widths of the figure. I forgot that command, so if you know it, that would be helpful.

What I really want is some type of `maximize_figure()` function if possible.

Comment: Why do you care whether the figure window is maximized when you're not converting to a raster format?

Comment: @horchler, yes duplicate I guess. Sorry. I don't know what to do now. Delete this question? I couldn't find the one you linked me to before I created this question, even though I searched.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When opening a new figure, you can pass arguments to the [`figure`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) function:

```
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
```

A full list of figure properties is also available [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html).

Comment: Hmm, I had this in my code and it seems to stop working for some reason. Once I restarted MATLAB it started working again. Any idea what would cause this?  By not working I mean that the window would not open maximized.

Comment: You don't have a variable named 'figure', do you?